# SQLAlchemy: Same table but different database engine

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a project that using SQLAlchemy and it connects to two different databases and both have same table name `sample_table`. Here is the current setup:

```
# In config/base.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database

...
...
...

db1_engine = create_engine(app.config['DB1_URI'], echo = False, pool_recycle = 1800)

if not database_exists(db1_engine.url):
    create_database(db1_engine.url)

print(database_exists(db1_engine.url))

db2_engine = create_engine(app.config['DB2_URI'], echo = False, pool_recycle = 1800)

if not database_exists(db2_engine.url):
    create_database(db2_engine.url)

print(database_exists(db2_engine.url)
...
...
...
```

-

```
# In database1/sample_table.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from config.base import Base

class SampleTable(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'sample_table'
   id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
   ...
   ...
```

-

```
# In database2/sample_table.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from config.base import Base

class SampleTable(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'sample_table'
   id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
   ...
   ...
```

-

```
# In controllers/db1.py
from config.base import db1_engine
from database1.sample_table import SampleTable

generate_db1_tables():
   if not db1_engine.dialect.has_table(db1_engine.connect(), "sample_table"):
    SampleTable.__table__.create(db1_engine)
```

-

```
# In controllers/db2.py
from config.base import db2_engine
from database2.sample_table import SampleTable

generate_db2_tables():
   if not db2_engine.dialect.has_table(db2_engine.connect(), "sample_table"):
    SampleTable.__table__.create(db2_engine)
```

-

```
# In app/app.py
from controllers.db1 import generate_db1_tables
from controllers.db2 import generate_db2_tables
...
...
generate_db1_tables()
generate_db2_tables()
...
...
```

And when I run the above codes, I got:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'sample_table' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

But when I add `__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}` in each model, `sample_table` from `database2` have the same fields in `sample_table` in `database1`. They have different structure.

What is the best practice in working on projects like this?

Note that the purpose of creating the databases and tables is to simulate the work in localhost. The databases and tables already exist in production.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone encounters the same scenario, I got fixed the error by updating the following:

```
# In config/base.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database

...
...
...

db1_engine = create_engine(app.config['DB1_URI'], echo = False, pool_recycle = 1800)
if not database_exists(db1_engine.url):
    create_database(db1_engine.url)

print(database_exists(db1_engine.url))
...
...
...
Db1Base = declarative_base()
Db2Base = declarative_base()
```

-

```
# In database1/sample_table.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from config.base import Db1Base

class SampleTable(Db1Base):
...
...
...
```

-

```
# In database2/sample_table.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from config.base import Db2Base

class SampleTable(Db2Base):
...
...
...
```